Why am I not seeing continuity between MC cable sheathing and ground wires?
Using a multimeter, I checked the continuity of the aluminum sheathing against any of the conductor wires (black/white/green) and there is no continuity to any of them
And then, when I wired the 3 conductors to a plug and plugged it in an outlet (which is connected to main panel), I tested the continuity again and the sheathing has continuity to the ground wire and neutral (green and white).
Photos for reference. Note that the other end of the wire is terminated (not connected to anything)



Where's the other end of the MC?  Wrong plug for MC.

the other end is terminated and not connected to anything. i am just trying to understand how it become bonded so plug is for just testing purposes only

Your use of terminology is confusing. "Terminated" in electrical terms literally means "connected to something", but you're saying it's the opposite... Unterminated means that it's just hanging freely and not connected to something.

That’s normal. The green wire is insulated and it never connects to the metal covering of the cable inside the cable.
It’s your responsibility to ground the metal cover. Generally that happens by clamping it to a metal junction box that is grounded.
In the second picture, the continuity to ground is probably due to the cover touching some grounded metal outside the photographed area. You’d see the same continuity between the shell and ground if you unplugged the plug and put your black meter probe in the ground pin hole directly.

Oh my! you are right. The metal clad is touching a duct work. when i removed it, the continuity stops.. then i touched it to the metal part of the extension and it showed continuity again. Now it's clear that any metal parts it touches that is somehow connected to the main panel is grounded. thanks nobody!
